# Json to Javascript Object Array

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am trying to create a javascript object as input for a bootstrap treeview. I have php that grabs data from mysql and json encodes the results into the following structure:

```
{"Company 1":{"Production":["Brands","Categories","Products","Stocks"],"Sales":["Customers","Orders","Staffs","Stores"]},"Company 2":{"Production":["Brands","Categories","Products","Stocks"],"Sales":["Customers","Orders","Staffs","Stores"]}}
```

PHP code to produce that json:

```
$databases=[];
foreach($result as $row){
$database=$row["database"];
$schema=$row["schema"];
$table=$row["object"];
if(!array_key_exists($database, $databases))
    $databases[$database]=[];
if(!array_key_exists($schema, $databases[$database]))
    $databases[$database][$schema]=[];
array_push($databases[$database][$schema], $table);
}

echo json_encode($databases);
```

But I am struggling to get that json structure into the nested array of JavaScript objects required. Below is the desired structure:

```
[ { text: "Company 1", nodes: [ { text: "Production", nodes: [ { text: "Brands" }, { text: "Categories" }, { text: "Products" }, { text: "Stocks" } ] }, { text: "Sales", nodes: [ { text: "Customers" }, { text: "Orders" }, { text: "Staffs" }, { text: "Stores" } ] } ] }, { text: "Company 2", nodes: [ { text: "Production", nodes: [ { text: "Brands" }, { text: "Categories" }, { text: "Products" }, { text: "Stocks" } ] }, { text: "Sales", nodes: [ { text: "Customers" }, { text: "Orders" }, { text: "Staffs" }, { text: "Stores" } ] } ] } ];
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: If you can show the PHP array $result, then it will easy for us to figure out the structure of the array and how to manipulate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a recursive `flatItem` function to do that.
I also introduce a `array_map_with_keys` helper function because PHP's own `array_map` function ignore keys and in your case, we need it.

```
function array_map_with_keys($callback, $array){
  return array_map($callback, array_keys($array), $array);
}

function flatItem($key, $value) {
  if(is_array($value)){
    return 
      ["text" => $key,
       "nodes" => array_map_with_keys("flatItem", $value)
      ];  
  }else{
    return ["text" => $value];
  }
}

$converted = array_map_with_keys("flatItem", $databases);

echo json_encode($converted);
```

Result is what you expect :

```
[{"text":"Company 1","nodes":[{"text":"Production","nodes":[{"te
xt":"Brands"},{"text":"Categories"},{"text":"Products"},{"text":
"Stocks"}]},{"text":"Sales","nodes":[{"text":"Customers"},{"text
":"Orders"},{"text":"Staffs"},{"text":"Stores"}]}]},{"text":"Com
pany 2","nodes":[{"text":"Production","nodes":[{"text":"Brands"}
,{"text":"Categories"},{"text":"Products"},{"text":"Stocks"}]},{
"text":"Sales","nodes":[{"text":"Customers"},{"text":"Orders"},{
"text":"Staffs"},{"text":"Stores"}]}]}]
```

you can pass it on to the js.

Comment: Awesome, many thanks. The array_map_with_keys function was smart.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = {
  "Company 1": {
    "Production": ["Brands", "Categories", "Products", "Stocks"],
    "Sales": ["Customers", "Orders", "Staffs", "Stores"]
  },
  "Company 2": {
    "Production": ["Brands", "Categories", "Products", "Stocks"],
    "Sales": ["Customers", "Orders", "Staffs", "Stores"]
  }
}

function converter(data) {
  return Object.entries(data).reduce((converted, [key, val]) => {
    const element = {
      text: key,
      nodes: [...Object.entries(val).map(([key2, val2]) => {
        return {
          text: key2,
          nodes: [...Object.values(val2).map(val3 => {
            return {
              text: val3
            }
          })]
        }
      })]
    }
    converted.push(element);
    return converted
  }, []);
}

console.log(converter(data))
```

Comment: Great JS solution! Only selected the PHP solution because I would rather do it on the server side, but I will most certainly learn from this and use it in other scenarios